# Как убрать текст с загрузочного экрана Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

При запуске ос, перед заставкой с загрузкой и логотипом выводятся какие-то логи и текст. Я понимаю что это никак не влияет на работу систему, просто вопрос эстетики, на федоре например такого нету.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел три способа:

1. В документации Arch Linux есть целая [статья](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/silent_boot) на эту тему. Можно изменить systemd-fsck-root.service и systemd-fsck@.service, что не трудно, но перед этим надо сделать так, чтобы проверка файлов происходила через systemd, а как это сделать в Ubuntu я не нашел.
2. Добавляем fsck.mode=skip до quiet и splash, чтобы получилась такая строка `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash"` , что отключает проверку файловой системы в принципе. Работает.
3. ```
   sudo -i
   echo FRAMEBUFFER=y > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
   update-initramfs -u
   exit
   ```

   Понятия не имею что здесь происходит, но это работает, и , как я понял, не отключает проверку а лишь ее скрывает.

Answer (score 0):

В /etc/default/grub в командлайн добавь loglevel=2 и сделай конфигурацию update-grub2

Comment: Не помогло, fsck все равно выводится

Comment: убирал както... надо вспомнить

Comment: а разве это хорошо, убирать проверку fs?

Comment: саму проверку не убираю, убираю её вывод